# Compute engine: upgrade Ubuntu before 14.04 (Trusty) deprecation

Tags: ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, ubuntu-14.04, google-compute-engine

I received a mail from Google Cloud Platform telling me:
"Google Compute Engine image based on Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty) will be deprecated on April 30, 2019."

I have different GCE instances using Ubuntu 14.04.
On these instances I run some java or python softwares or I installed some software like databases or CRM for example or other software in use on my company.

Which is the best way to upgrade the OS?
The only way is to create new instances and re-install and migrate all my software? This represents a lot of work.
There are some alternative approaches?

I read that is not recommended to upgrade the OS in place.

I hope to get useful suggestions, thank you very much!

Comment: This answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54833139/8016720

Comment: I found this answer too: https://serverfault.com/questions/826759/how-to-update-from-debian-7-to-debian-8-on-google-compute-engine.
It says: "it is not recommended to upgrade the OS in place. Instead you should deploy the application on an image of the next version."
So... ...is it a good approach to use ubuntu-release-upgrader?

Comment: I don't have an opinion. I have not upgraded 14.04 to a newer version. However, with most major OS upgrades it best to start fresh and move the applications to the new OS.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade from Ubuntu 14 to Ubuntu 18 LTS is a bit tricky because this is now having systemd and also lot of things changed like the network which is now using YAML.
Sure you can upgrade it with a simple do-release-upgrade but is not what I would recommend.

**create new instances with Ubuntu 18  and migrate everything like applications and databases to it is what I would do, sure there is more work but it is safe**

If you still need to do an upgrade of running instances be sure you have a backup of the data,configurations etc. and maybe do a test upgrade with a non-important instance.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach to upgrade the OS would be to:

1) Create a [snapshot](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots#creating_snapshots) of the current disk.

2) Run the upgrade of your OS on said instance.

3) [Mount](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/mount-drive-from-command-line-ubuntu-linux/) the snapshot disk to the upgraded instance.

4) Access and transfer the applications/programs/files that you need from the snapshot disk to the upgraded instance.

The reason being is that it's always good to have a backup of your files/your applications in case of any unexpected events. You'll also avoid creating a new instance and have everything done on your current instance.

If for any reason the upgrade did not go well, you'll still have a backup of your disk and you can spin a new VM and start from step 3.